# buttons to revert and add item to menu aren't working

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I right-clicked Applications -> clicked Edit Menu -> reset -> confirmed, but Ubuntu One, which I accidetanlly removed wasn't added.

Although Ubuntu One was removed, I tried to remove duplicated items in right-click Applications -> click Edit Menu -> Applications -> Others, but the duplicated items weren't removed.

How to solve these problems?

UPDATE:

I uninstalled gnome-menus and libgnome-menu2, because of the post at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=426204, but now Gnome App Central is gone from Applications menu.

Comment: which version of Ubuntu?  9.10? 10.04?

Comment: the version is 9.10